# How to read Google Analytics events data for Android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I would like to track user actions and user settings in my android app, so I've added the following code (executed when user presses particular button):

```
if (user_name != "") has_name = 1;
...
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_name", (long) has_name).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_address", (long) has_address).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_operator", (long) has_operator).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_passport", (long) has_passport).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_phonenumber", (long) has_phonenumber).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_mo_consent", (long) has_mo_consent).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_other_docs", (long) has_other_docs).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_screenshot", (long) has_screenshot).build());

easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "complaint_region", email_to, null).build());
```

Now I see the following results for particular date -

EVENT ACTION: send_mail » EVENT CATEGORY: ui_action
[image: ea:send_mail-ec:ui_action]

EVENT CATEGORY: ui_action » EVENT ACTION: complaint_region
[image: ec:ui_action_ea:complaint_region]

I can not understand - should not be total number of events `complaint_region` multiplied by 8 (number of event labels for `send_mail`) be equal to `send_mail` total events? `76*8 != 1038`.

And, the main question - how many times all users pressed the button? `76`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where the problem is - I've added `complaint_region` event only in the latest version of the application, when many users still use previous version. So, the correct answer is -

~120 users pressed button ~130 times.